# Large file upload through Browser (100 GB)

Tags: php, jquery, file-upload

Is there any way to upload large files (**more than 80 Gb**) through a web browser? Previously I have been uploading files (img, png, jpg) using plupload but it seems not to be working for larger files. I would also like to know how to implement a web page where users could upload like Mega.co.nz or Drive.google.com.
If it is impossible to do it using web development tools, can anyone guide me about how I can divide & upload a file in segments?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the JavaScript [Blob](http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/#dfn-Blob) object to slice large files into smaller chunks and transfer these to the server to be merged together. This has the added benefit of being able to pause/resume downloads and indicate progress.

If you don't fancy doing it yourself there are existing solutions that use this approach. One example is [HTML5 Uploader](http://html5uploader.filkor.org/) by [Filkor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1039537/filkor).